# From log.normal to normal

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I have the following issue.  With a Monte Carlo simulation I have generated a data set, x values and their frequencies. When I plot the histogram I noticed that the shape of the distribution is skewed. The distribution of ln(x) is almost a perfect Gaussian distribution. As far as I have understood this right a quantity is ln-normal distributed when ln(x) is normal distributed. So what then I calculated $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the distribution of ln(x). As I mentioned I assumed that ln(x) is normal distributed so that its PDF is $y=A\times e^{-0.5\times(ln(x)-\mu)^2/\sigma^2}$.

Now, how do I get the standard deviation of x (being ln-normal distributed)
and its expected value?

Comment: You could consult this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) - it has all the necessary formulas (derivations are a matter of a few simple integrations).

Comment: i alreday had a look at the this, but the problem is that in these they use the PDF of X and it would be $1/(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\times x)\times e^{-0.5\times(ln(x)-\mu)^2/\sigma^2}$

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem: the expectation of $\ln(x)$ is $\mu$, while its variance is $\sigma^2$. Whereas the mean of $x$ is $\exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$ and variance is $[\exp(\sigma^2) - 1]\exp(2\mu + \sigma^2)$.

Comment: I have added the derivation details to my answer, in case this is what posed difficulty.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+standard+deviation

Comment: @Vadim with mean you mean the median?

Comment: By *mean* I mean the *mean* - the mathematical expectation of the variable. In our case
$\mathbb{E} [\ln(x)] = \mu$, whereas $\mathbb{E} [x] = \exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$.